# Bundler is deprecating bundle console in favor of bin/console. Can anyone provide more clarity as to how bin/console should work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a custom ruby gem that relies heavily on `bundle console`. Nothing special or fancy, just an interactive console with the set of gems defined by the Gemfile included. We use the console a lot during development.

Currently when I run the command, I receive the following deprecation message:

> [DEPRECATED] bundle console will be replaced by `bin/console` generated by `bundle gem <name>`

Digging around in the [bundler docs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bundler/bundler/master/UPGRADING.md) I found the following explanation:

> - The `bundle console` will be removed and replaced with `bin/console`.
>
> Over time we found `bundle console` hard to maintain because every
>   user would want to add her own specific tweaks to it. In order to
>   ease maintenance and reduce bikeshedding discussions, we're removing
>   the `bundle console` command in favor of a `bin/console` script
>   created by `bundle gem` on gem generation that users can tweak to
>   their needs.

Can anyone with knowledge provide a more detailed explanation? This gem currently does not have a `bin` directory. I'm happy to make one, I'm just not sure what should be in the file. Running `bundle gem` as described in the note above raises an error (as expected).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the file that is generated at `bin/console`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "bundler/setup"
require "(your gem name here)"

# You can add fixtures and/or initialization code here to make experimenting
# with your gem easier. You can also use a different console, if you like.

# (If you use this, don't forget to add pry to your Gemfile!)
# require "pry"
# Pry.start

require "irb"
IRB.start(__FILE__)
```

You can see the template in the rubygems [GitHub repo](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/bundler/lib/bundler/templates/newgem/bin/console.tt).

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you so much for your help.