# Automatically load Dotenv on my ruby console

Tags: ruby, sinatra, bundler, irb

I'd like to automatically run `Dotenv.load('.env.development')` whenever I launch up a ruby console, it could either be from `bundle console` or alternatively `irb`.  I'm using Sinatra, not Rails, and I'm not sure how to run some commands on console start.. I'd prefer to do this without a bash script, instead using the internal capabilities of the tools.. If there's a place to put ruby code on the start of a ruby console that would solve my issue and also allow for future console customization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `.irbrc` file in our project's directory which is loaded automatically when an IRB session is started. And add something like this to that file:

```
begin
  require 'dotenv'
  Dotenv.load('.env.development')
rescue => e
  puts "loading Dotenv failed. because: #{e.message}"
end
```

Read more about the [`.irbrc` file in the Ruby-Docs](https://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/irb.html#S2).

Comment: This seems promising!  Will try it out

Comment: It successfully reads from ~/.irbrc, but doesnt seem to look for a .irbrc in the folder.

Comment: That is surprising because even the [latest version of ruby](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/lib/irb.rb#L87) has this behavior documented in their docs. Did you really test just a `.irbrc` file? Because if there is a `~/.irbrc` file then a `.irbrc` file will not be read anymore.

Comment: Tried it again, and it worked, must've been a typo on my end.

Answer (score 0):

You try folliwing the documentation of gem(sorry my ignorance I don't know anything about sinatra)?:

[Documentation dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#sinatra-or-plain-ol-ruby)

Install the gem:

```
$ gem install dotenv
```

By default, load will look for a file called .env in the current working directory. Pass in multiple files and they will be loaded in order. The first value set for a variable will win.

```
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load('file1.env', 'file2.env')
```

In your case i think should be:

```
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load('.env.development')
```

In ruby vanilla I dont know if possible, I think yes.

Comment: I don't want to have to type `Dotenv.load('.env.development')` each time I do the console.  I know I can manually do it this way, question is how to automatically run

Comment: If u are using sinatra I think if u have console of sinatra u dont need load the env again, but when you use irb I thinks this setting dont work.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to creating a ./bin/console script [ala Bundler's gem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63716336/378622).

I created this `bin/console` file as a temporary solution, but I'm curious whether I can get @spickermann's answer (which I incorporated here) with irbrc to work with a same-directory .irbrc

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

begin
  require 'dotenv'
  Dotenv.load('.env.development')
rescue => e
  puts "loading Dotenv failed. because: #{e.message}"
end

require "irb"
IRB.start(__FILE__)
```